# Example of PPT channel that is not entanglement breaking

Tags: operator-algebras, quantum-computation, quantum-information

I was looking at the PPT$^2$ conjecture (that if $\Phi$ is a PPT quantum channel, then $\Phi^2$ is entanglement breaking) and it said that there are examples of PPT channels that are not entanglement breaking. However, I can neither find any examples nor think of them. What is an example of such a channel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By Choi's theorem, $T:M_n\rightarrow M_n$ is completely positive iff  $A=(Id\otimes T)(vv^t)$ is a state (non-normalized) in $M_n\otimes M_n$ , where $v=\sum_{i=1}^ne_i\otimes e_i$ and $\{e_1,\ldots,e_n\}$ is the canonical basis of $\mathbb{C}^n$.

Since $vv^t\in M_n\otimes M_n$ is an entangled state (non-normalized) then
 if $A=(Id\otimes T)(vv^t)$ is entangled then $T$ is not entanglement breaking.

Let $A\in M_n\otimes M_n$, $n>2$, be any PPT entangled state. Its associated completely positive map $T$ is not entanglement breaking, but $S(\cdot)=T(\cdot)^t$ still is completely positive $($because $(Id\otimes T(\cdot)^t)(vv^t)$ is a state).

So $S((\cdot)^t)^t=T((\cdot)^t)$ is completely positive too.

Let $R\in M_n$ be such that $R^*T^*(Id)R=Id$. Then $RT(\cdot)R^*$ is completely positive and its adjoint $R^*T^*(\cdot)R$ is unital. So $RT(\cdot)R^*$ is a PPT channel, but it is not entanglement breaking.